# How to create download link to download a file instead of redirecting to browser?

Tags: php, html

I am trying to put a link to download a pdf from server, instead of redirecting the browser to open the pdf in another page. I have seen such options in many sites but unable to get the code. And most people says it should be possible with php only, could anyone help me for this.

Answer (score 5):

Redirect it to a php page with this code:

```
$path_to_file = '/var/www/somefile.pdf'; //Path to file you want downloaded
$file_name = "somefile.pdf"; //Name of file for download
header('Pragma: public');   // required
header('Expires: 0');    // no cache
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$file_name.'"');
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
readfile($path_to_file);
die();
```

Answer (score 3):

or you can include this in `.htaccess`

```
<FilesMatch "\.(?i:pdf)$">
  ForceType application/octet-stream
  Header set Content-Disposition attachment
</FilesMatch>
```

Comment: This is a good solution if they want all pdfs on the site to have the same behavior.

Comment: @registered user Will you please explain.What is this

Comment: This is using apache / .htaccess to dictate the header information for .pdf files instead of php.

Answer (score 0):

You can sometimes change the http headers:

```
header("Content-Type: application/force-download");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"lol.pdf\"");
```

Like so. But some browsers actually prevent this for security reasons.

#### Edit

Since I realised it wasn't clear. These headers would be sent from another page which actually reads in the file and send it to the browser with these headers.

The link would then point it's `href` attribute to this PHP page which reads in the file and sends the headers.

Answer (score 0):

From php

```
    header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
    header("Content-Disposition:attachment;filename=myfile.pdf");
```

And then the file content

Or from Apache

```
<FilesMatch "\.(?i:pdf)$">
  ForceType application/octet-stream
  Header set Content-Disposition attachment
</FilesMatch>
```

Comment: so you saw the Sammaye and my answer

Comment: No, I was unaware of the other answers