# How to download a PDF file instead showing it in Adobe Reader?

Tags: php, download

I'm trying to create a download link for a PDF file. It works fine if Adobe Reader is installed, but if I uninstall it, it tries to open in browser and fails.

Please tell me what is the actual problem about this?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: You can't control a file once it's on a client's machine.

Comment: Exact duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12565683/how-to-create-download-link-to-download-a-file-instead-of-redirecting-to-browser/12565743#12565743

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that when adobe reader is installed than it automaitcally gets the header of .pdf file and show the file.

You can use this.It will always prompt to download the file ..

```
$path="uploads/";

$actualfilename=$path.$row["name"];

//name of the file or location of file..
if($typeofview=="download") {
    @readfile($actualfilename);
    header('Content-type: application/pdf');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $actualfilename. '"');
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($actualfilename));
    header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');
    exit;
}
```

Comment: The posted wants to tell you: it is a question of the headers you send.

Comment: what do you want to say @arkascha?

Comment: whats this $fakefilename and $row["name"] ??

Comment: see the edited answer `$row['name']` is name of file like uploads/a.pdf

Comment: @jhonraymos The question was: "what is the actual problem?". You did not really answer to that question, but gave a (good) example solution instead. All is fine :-)

Comment: it not show save option it automatically open it in adobe reader . and show save option when i remove the .pdf extention from the file.

Comment: @user1688258 you can tell the browser to force download the file however this is blocked on many browser for security reasons but try adding: `header("Content-Type: application/force-download");` before the content-disposition header. BUt most likely the adobe reader is overtaking the normal headers and doing its own thing.

Comment: @user1688258 This might also be a browser setting where you have told it to open these files by default instead of show the option to open or save.

Comment: I m using fire fox ... from where i check this setting in my browser ?

Comment: @user1688258 Ah firefox, ok I just realised the default install of firefox forces the open in adobe reader as does chrome. You can find the setting under options->applications it will show a default action, set it to always ask

Comment: @jhonraymos yes file location is correct . it save when we remove file extention from the end ?

Comment: @Sammaye it still not work .. after changing the default to always\ ask

Comment: `header('Content-Disposition: attachment');' i am not sure but this may work

Answer (score 0):

This is a duplicate of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12565683/how-to-create-download-link-to-download-a-file-instead-of-redirecting-to-browser/12565743#12565743) but here is the answer:

```
$path_to_file = '/var/www/somefile.pdf'; //Path to file you want downloaded
$file_name = "somefile.pdf"; //Name of file for download
header('Pragma: public');   // required
header('Expires: 0');    // no cache
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$file_name.'"');
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
readfile($path_to_file);
die();
```